# Converting UTF-8 iso-8859 bytes - String.to_charlist

Tags: utf-8, elixir

I have run into an odd problem.  I have a program that receives data in bytes from an external source, which I in return perform some business logic and send a reply. We have come into an odd issue with String.to_charlist.

Try this in iex:

```
String.to_charlist <<169, 99, 111, 114, 94, 51, 94, 51, 94, 66, 52, 57, 49, 49, 49, 32, 32, 49, 48, 51, 53, 94, 67, 79, 77, 80, 76, 69, 84, 69, 68, 94, 49, 49, 52, 50, 52, 53, 94, 75>>
```

This will throw the following error:

```
** (UnicodeConversionError) invalid encoding starting at <<169, 99, 111, 114, 94, 51, 94, 51, 94, 66, 52, 57, 49, 49, 49, 32, 32, 49, 48, 51, 53, 94, 67, 79, 77, 80, 76, 69, 84, 69, 68, 94, 49, 49, 52, 50, 52, 53, 94, 75>>
    (elixir) lib/string.ex:2035: String.to_charlist/1
```

Now if you strip off the first byte and in turn try:

```
String.to_charlist <<99, 111, 114, 94, 51, 94, 51, 94, 66, 52, 57, 49, 49, 49, 32, 32, 49, 48, 51, 53, 94, 67, 79, 77, 80, 76, 69, 84, 69, 68, 94, 49, 49, 52, 50, 52, 53, 94, 75>>
```

You get:

> 'cor^3^3^B49111  1035^COMPLETED^114245^K'

Is there a different way I should be converting these bytes to a string? I understand some characters like 169 may not be displayable, but what is the recommended way of handling such?

Thanks for your help.

I did find this:

```
<<169 :: utf8, 0>>
```

Returns <<194, 169, 0>> which added the 194. So if you paste this into iex the output appears to be correct.

```
<<194, 169, 99, 111, 114, 94, 51, 94, 51, 94, 66, 52, 57, 49, 49, 49, 32, 32, 49, 48, 51, 53, 94, 67, 79, 77, 80, 76, 69, 84, 69, 68, 94, 49, 49, 52, 50, 52, 53, 94, 75>>
```

Do I need to write a function that loops through the bytes and calls <> then reduces on the bytes returned (except for the 0 concat)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.to_charlist/1` is redundant in the first place:

```
String.to_charlist <<99, 111, 114, 94, 51, 94, 51, 94>>
```

works only because `utf8` and `latin1` share the same codepoints in the interval `1–127`. The below would be enough to get a perfectly valid binary:

```
<<99, 111, 114, 94, 51, 94, 51, 94>>
#⇒ "cor^3^3^"
```

Unfortunately, what you receive is not in `utf8` encoding and Elixir has no built-in tools to convert binaries between encoding. You cannot just drop meaningful symbols.

I would suggest using [`codepagex`](https://github.com/tallakt/codepagex) package for that conversion:

```
Codepagex.from_string(<<99, 111, 114, 94, 51, 94, 51, 94>>, :iso_8859_1)
#⇒ "cor^3^3^"
```

---

Other way round would be to use erlang’s [`unicode.characters_to_binary/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html#characters_to_binary-2):

```
:unicode.characters_to_binary(
  <<169, 99, 111, 114, 94, 51, 94, 51, 94>>, :latin1, :utf8
)
#⇒ "©cor^3^3^"
```

---

Another solution using [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension:

```
to_string(for <<c :: 8 <- <<169, 99, 111, 114, 94, 51, 94, 51, 94>> >>, do: c)
#⇒ "©cor^3^3^"
```

Comment: The bytes you passed into from_string do not contain the 169. I tried this: `Codepagex.from_string(<<169, 99, 111, 114, 94, 51, 94, 51, 94, 66, 52, 57, 49, 49, 49, 32, 32, 49, 48, 51, 53, 94, 67, 79, 77, 80, 76, 69, 84, 69, 68, 94, 49, 49, 52, 50, 52, 53, 94, 75>>, :iso_8859_1)` and received: `{:error, "Invalid bytes for encoding"}`

Comment: 1. I have updated the answer, probably you might stick to erlang solution. 2. I do not know what the encoding is it. Try `:latin1` instead of `:iso_8859_1`, or use `replace_nonexistent` as shown in their documentation.

Comment: thanks for your help. I used your solution. What is interesting is if I pass the sames bytes as a charlist to to_string it works fine... Very odd.. Thanks for your help:  `to_string [169, 99, 111, 114, 94, 49, 94, 49, 94]`

Comment: Welcome. I have updated the answer with the third variant (using comprehension.)

Comment: How come you can call `String.to_charlist` with a binary argument?  There doesn't seem to be anything in `iex> h String.to_charlist` that allows that, to wit: *Converts a string into a charlist.*  Can a binary always be used for a String argument?  Yes, I've read that a String is a UTF-8 encoded binary, and I just tried `"é" === <<12 :: size(4), 3 :: size(4), 10 :: size(4), 9 :: size(4) >>` and I got true.

Comment: I am sorry, I am unable to understand what bugs you here. String and binary are synonims.

Comment: Nothing "bugs" me.  I'm trying to understand elixir.  *String and binary are synonims*--Thanks!